# Jenkins API HTTPError: 401 Client Error: Unauthorized for url

Tags: python, http, jenkins

```
from jenkinsapi.jenkins import Jenkins
JENKINS_URL = "<jenkins-url>"
JENKINS_USERNAME = "<username>"
JENKINS_PASSWORD = "<password>"

self.jenkins_server = Jenkins(JENKINS_URL, username=JENKINS_USERNAME, password=JENKINS_PASSWORD)
```

It gives me following error : `HTTPError: 401 Client Error: Unauthorized for url`

StackTrace:

```
Failed request at http://<jenkins-url>/api/python with params: {'tree': 'jobs[name,color,url]'} jobs[name,color,url]
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "minimal_test_jenkins.py", line 11, in __init__
    self.jenkins_server = Jenkins(JENKINS_URL, username=JENKINS_USERNAME, password=JENKINS_PASSWORD)
  File "/Users/bapac/Downloads/jenkins/lib/python3.7/site-packages/jenkinsapi/jenkins.py", line 77, in __init__
    JenkinsBase.__init__(self, baseurl, poll=not lazy)
  File "/Users/bapac/Downloads/jenkins/lib/python3.7/site-packages/jenkinsapi/jenkinsbase.py", line 38, in __init__
    self.poll()
  File "/Users/bapac/Downloads/jenkins/lib/python3.7/site-packages/jenkinsapi/jenkinsbase.py", line 60, in poll
    data = self._poll(tree=tree)
  File "/Users/bapac/Downloads/jenkins/lib/python3.7/site-packages/jenkinsapi/jenkins.py", line 82, in _poll
    if not tree else tree)
  File "/Users/bapac/Downloads/jenkins/lib/python3.7/site-packages/jenkinsapi/jenkinsbase.py", line 84, in get_data
    response.raise_for_status()
  File "/Users/bapac/Downloads/jenkins/lib/python3.7/site-packages/requests/models.py", line 941, in raise_for_status
    raise HTTPError(http_error_msg, response=self)
requests.exceptions.HTTPError: 401 Client Error: Unauthorized for url: http://<jenkins-url>/api/python?tree=jobs%5Bname%2Ccolor%2Curl%5D
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unauthorized for url i.e. 401 Client Error means one of the 3 things is wrong
Jenkins Username/Password or Additional Credential which are needed aren't provided.

I resolved it by correcting my password (which was incorrect previously!)

Answer (score 2):

```
python3 -m pip freeze | grep requests

python3 -m pip install requests==2.25.0
```

or python2

will fix the problem