Throwing an Error while triggering the Jenkins build in GitHub Actions
I am doing an GitHub Actions workflow that triggers the build in Jenkins. Below are the files are created that triggers the build.
config.json:
{
    "buildConfig": {
        "jobName": "subbu_project"
    }
}

trigger_build.yml in GitHub workflows:
---

name: Trigger Jenkins Build

on:
  push:
    branches:
      - "main"

jobs:
  trigger-jenkins:
    runs-on: self-hosted

    steps:
      - name: Trigger Jenkins Build
        shell: bash
        env:
          JENKINS_URL: ${{ secrets.JENKINS_URL || 'http://localhost:8080' }}
          JENKINS_USER: ${{ secrets.JENKINS_USER || 'subbaramaiah_chevuru' }}
          JENKINS_API_TOKEN: ${{ secrets.JENKINS_API_TOKEN }}
          JOB_NAME: ${{ env.JOB_NAME || 'subbu_project' }}
          BUILD_NUMBER: ${{ env.BUILD_NUMBER || '001' }}
          DEPLOY_ENVIRONMENT: development
        run: |
          # Trim trailing slashes from JENKINS_URL
          TRIMMED_JENKINS_URL=$(echo "$JENKINS_URL" | sed 's:/*$::')
          # Clean job name (no need to modify)
          CLEAN_JOB_NAME="$JOB_NAME"
          # Construct the full URL
          FULL_URL="${TRIMMED_JENKINS_URL}/job/${CLEAN_JOB_NAME}/build"
          echo "Full URL: $FULL_URL"
          # Execute the curl command to trigger the Jenkins build
          echo "Executing curl command:"
          curl -v "$FULL_URL" \
               --user "$JENKINS_USER:$JENKINS_API_TOKEN" \
               --header "Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded" \
               --data-urlencode "BUILD_NUMBER=$BUILD_NUMBER" \
               --data-urlencode "DEPLOY_ENVIRONMENT=$DEPLOY_ENVIRONMENT"

Do you have a Jenkins instance running at localhost:8080 on that self-hosted runner? - Asked by @Azeem
I have installed and started the Jenkins and Action Runner in the  PowerShell WSL and below is the output in the GitHub Action
[trigger-jenkins][1] :
Full URL: ***/job/subbu_project/build
Executing curl command:
*   Trying 192.168.241.134:8080...
  % Total    % Received % Xferd  Average Speed   Time    Time     Time  Current
                                 Dload  Upload   Total   Spent    Left  Speed

  0     0    0     0    0     0      0      0 --:--:-- --:--:-- --:--:--     0* Connected to 192.168.241.134 (192.168.241.134) port 8080 (#0)
* Server auth using Basic with user '***'
> POST /job/subbu_project/build HTTP/1.1
> Host: 192.168.241.134:8080
> Authorization: Basic Y2hldnVydV9zdWJiYXJhbWFpYWg6***
> User-Agent: curl/7.81.0
> Accept: */*
> Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded
> Content-Length: 47
> 
} [47 bytes data]
* Mark bundle as not supporting multiuse
< HTTP/1.1 401 Unauthorized
< Date: Fri, 30 Aug 2024 16:35:24 GMT
< X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff
< Set-Cookie: remember-me=; Path=/; Expires=Thu, 01-Jan-1970 00:00:00 GMT; Max-Age=0
* Authentication problem. Ignoring this.
< WWW-Authenticate: Basic realm="Jenkins"
< Cache-Control: must-revalidate,no-cache,no-store
< Content-Type: text/html;charset=iso-8859-1
< Content-Length: 473
< Server: Jetty(10.0.20)
< 
{ [473 bytes data]

100   520  100   473  100    47   2126    211 --:--:-- --:--:-- --:--:--  2407
* Connection #0 to host 192.168.241.134 left intact
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html;charset=ISO-8859-1"/>
<title>Error 401 Unauthorized</title>
</head>
<body><h2>HTTP ERROR 401 Unauthorized</h2>
<table>
<tr><th>URI:</th><td>/job/subbu_project/build</td></tr>
<tr><th>STATUS:</th><td>401</td></tr>
<tr><th>MESSAGE:</th><td>Unauthorized</td></tr>
<tr><th>SERVLET:</th><td>Stapler</td></tr>
</table>
<hr/><a href="https://eclipse.org/jetty">Powered by Jetty:// 10.0.20</a><hr/>

</body>
</html>
##[debug]Finishing: Trigger Jenkins Build

By executing the command in locally also I am getting the same error as Error :
$ curl -v "http://192.168.241.134:8080/job/subbu_project/build" \
        >                --user "subbaramaiah_chevuru:11514daba6c763a40b32e7123eef7e78f1" \
>                --header "Jenkins-Crumb:3756f301ef6d0c8d22026bf7c6ba198c3e9a71f63ef9366ea7d81d124a85905f" \
>                --header "Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded" \
>                --data-urlencode "BUILD_NUMBER=001" \
        >                --data-urlencode "DEPLOY_ENVIRONMENT=development"
*   Trying 192.168.241.134:8080...
* Connected to 192.168.241.134 (192.168.241.134) port 8080 (#0)
* Server auth using Basic with user 'subbaramaiah_chevuru'
> POST /job/subbu_project/build HTTP/1.1
> Host: 192.168.241.134:8080
> Authorization: Basic c3ViYmFyYW1haWFoX2NoZXZ1cnU6MTE1MTRkYWJhNmM3NjNhNDBiMzJlNzEyM2VlZjdlNzhmMQ==
> User-Agent: curl/7.81.0
> Accept: */*
> Jenkins-Crumb:3756f301ef6d0c8d22026bf7c6ba198c3e9a71f63ef9366ea7d81d124a85905f
> Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded
> Content-Length: 47
>
* Mark bundle as not supporting multiuse
< HTTP/1.1 404 Not Found
< Date: Sat, 31 Aug 2024 09:46:22 GMT
< X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff
< Cache-Control: no-cache,no-store,must-revalidate
< Set-Cookie: JSESSIONID.11122400=node01rcar0q76b0tu6bqi1ddd7tff18.node0; Path=/; HttpOnly
< Expires: 0
< Content-Type: text/html;charset=utf-8
< X-Hudson-Theme: default
< Referrer-Policy: same-origin
< Cross-Origin-Opener-Policy: same-origin
< X-Hudson: 1.395
< X-Jenkins: 2.462.1
< X-Jenkins-Session: d1c5dd84
< X-Frame-Options: sameorigin
< X-Instance-Identity: MIIBIjANBgkqhkiG9w0BAQEFAAOCAQ8AMIIBCgKCAQEAwqhFMW++j5WAbGASVHTzI/xzPeWWXb/F6xfqeGQJCLFEZq7l0AtoAjiH9I4uPwDK94FtA+9orMy2VbJa/cZELSyZbfNHeeZVXEa4xgzeyLzQD+g1SWNpvvDWqpPbV8BvwWCSA21gZ3TqQ5/oqkcMfR3fmtLKp2aWn8YTxBuxRzirKz6o8VfwsiMDF5oU0bnxsYm4kJ8hdsQTwuvMA7kU5BlotTFA7hT5hbAKocpnBU9Ybi2pL48AwXSktWrBKbNnsUz9KA/gMgmc7OkxiLYjEo6TB2i90XS9f38plNjUuZ7b6D1oXbDj0FRw5SHteIchtwGoLh9bkAYH4FQkocSYMQIDAQAB
< Transfer-Encoding: chunked
< Server: Jetty(10.0.20)
<




  <!DOCTYPE html><html><head resURL="/static/d1c5dd84" data-rooturl="" data-resurl="/static/d1c5dd84" data-extensions-available="true" data-unit-test="false" data-imagesurl="/static/d1c5dd84/images" data-crumb-header="Jenkins-Crumb" data-crumb-value="ccf807f121e6e11d15597f94a9211501049538c9739b6bfe709c228a1d152534">



    <title>Not Found [Jenkins]</title>


Always enclose ${{...}} in single quotes to avoid unwanted shell-specific side effects. As you're already using env to set secrets as env vars, using secrets inside run part is redundant. You should directly reference those via env vars now.

See your updated workflow with env vars.

Thanks for commenting. I have updated and tried with the link provide updated workflow still encountered the same error

Does the value being assigned to CUSTOM_PARAM contain any double quotes in it?

Also, please edit your question and add the responses below that you've posted as answers. Remove the answers after that.

Yes I have tried the changes suggested but the error exits by editing the same question and deleted the posted answers.

What about CUSTOM_PARAM?

I added the CUSTOM_PARAM like as "DEPLOY_ENVIRONMENT=$DEPLOY_ENVIRONMENT”

Does running the same curl command from your local machine work with all the values in the env vars? Please test that if you haven't already and update it in your question also.

Yes I tried the curl command  locally and getting an error as unauthorized but i have given the PAT token in the command, still getting the error.

The closing double quotes for --user flag's value is missing in curl command for terminal.

Yes @Azeem , I have corrected the ***curl *** command and  got the html output. I have opened the html in browser page, but its showing as Not Found  and attached in the question.

Right. You should try to make it work from your local machine first. The same sequence should work from GHA workflow.

Thanks @Azeem, still I am getting the error while executing the command locally. It generates the html file, while trying to open that file getting the same Not Found Error in browser. I am not sure what went wrong with the command still trying to debug the issue. Please correct me where I have done wrong, if you have any thoughts or suggestions .

This is my Github  Repositiry link as below:
https://github.com/Subbaram1993/subbu_project.git
Please suggest if any thoughts to solve this issue.

Just looked at the repo. Apart from the above issue, you're hitting localhost:8080 for Jenkins . Is that intentional? It's not preinstalled on ubuntu-latest runner (Ubuntu 22.04). Your workflow doesn't contain anything related to that either. You need to verify and update that accordingly Most probably, you need to trigger build by hitting a publicly hosted Jenkins instance.

Forked and tested the minimal version of your script with hardcoded values and it seems to be working i.e. no syntax error. See workflow and its run. Also, checked your script with https://shellcheck.net/ and locally as well. Seemed to be worked fine without any syntax error.

Update workflow like this and test.

Let us continue this discussion in chat.

Thanks @Azeem for the suggestions on this, I have tried with Github runner actions by installing the provided Github Action (https://github.com/Subbaram1993/subbu_project/actions/runners?tab=self-hosted) and changed the yml file then executed the **workflow( https://github.com/Subbaram1993/subbu_project/blob/main/.github/workflows/trigger-jenkins-build.yml)**and the result **run(https://github.com/Subbaram1993/subbu_project/actions/runs/10614729022). The yml file is executed manually without any errors, but getting the same error as I mentioned previously Not Found in browser.

That's a self-hosted runner and from the script it looks like a Windows one as you're using Command Prompt (cmd) syntax. That's a different issue now. You can simply run the same sequence of commands on that self-hosted runner directly to make sure everything works fine. If it works correctly then run it via GHA.

Yes, its a Windows Command syntax. But with the same commands that are executed in the self-hosted runner still its same error in the runner also. I am still debugging the issue how to trigger the jenkins(runs as localhost:8080) build using yaml file.

Do you have a Jenkins instance running at localhost:8080 on that self-hosted runner?

Yes I have installed the Jenkins in PowerShell using WSL with instance running at [http://192.168.241.134:8080/] as self-hosted runner [https://github.com/Subbaram1993/subbu_project/settings/actions/runners] (Action Runners) . I have updated the query with output.

Right. It looks like a configuration issue. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60766794/jenkins-api-httperror-401-client-error-unauthorized-for-url.

Ok @Azeem,  from the given reference link the issue has solved by installing python to  or by themselves locally but in my case I don't have any python code. I tried by checking the credentials again but still same error ** Error 401 Unauthorized***. I am still debugging the credentials , if you have something in your mind or any suggestions Please posted. Thanks.

Well, it has now become a different problem altogether. You need to isolate it and post a new question. Make sure you include all the details in that. Jenkins should be running, accessible and functional. Add the curl command that works successfully from that machine directly.

Sure @Azeem,  if possible I had changed the **yml** file in my repository and the  link for  GitHub Action Result, if you have time please check the Action result post your suggestions if you have any. Thanks.

Looks like your workflow is not fixed for Bash as well. It's also hitting the local Jenkins instance, But, it's still getting 404 Not Found response. Have you verified that the curl command runs successfully locally on that machine?

Yes, in local also getting the same error 404 Not Found

Then, you need to fix that first. It might be a credentials or some configuration issue. I'm not sure about that. You need to verify that on your side.

Yes I am still debugging it where I went wrong either with curl or any thing need to check.

Thanks @Azeem for the support in this issue. I solved the above error by reconfiguring and recreating the job in Jenkins.

Good to hear that. You're welcome! So, it was some configuration issue? You might want to self-answer this with all the details to help others. All the best!

Yes @Azeem sure I will update this.

Looking at the code, I can infer that the only source of unexpected double quote is ${{ secrets.JENKINS_USER }} or ${{ secrets.JENKINS_API_TOKEN }}
To support a double quote in either of these values, try enclosing --user argument in single quotes:
--user '${{ secrets.JENKINS_USER }}:${{ secrets.JENKINS_API_TOKEN }}'

Another issue here is this line:
TRIMMED_JENKINS_URL=$(echo "${{ secrets.JENKINS_URL }}" | sed 's:/*$::')

echo will add '\n' to the url and sed will pass it through. This will cause the error you see.
A better option would be
TRIMMED_JENKINS_URL=$(echo -n "${{ secrets.JENKINS_URL }}" | sed 's:/*$::')


To troubleshoot the error, I first tested the curl command, which included the Jenkins credentials (JENKINS_USER, JENKINS_API_TOKEN) and other parameters, using Git Bash on Windows. I then ran the same setup using the Windows Subsystem for Linux (WSL) in PowerShell, where I had installed Git, Jenkins, and the GitHub Actions runners.
Here, below is the Error 401 Unauthorized I am getting whenever I triggered the Jenkins job using the GitHub Actions.
Despite multiple checks of the .yml file to verify the curl command, Jenkins credentials, and other services, the Jenkins job was still not being triggered by the GitHub Actions workflow.
Upon further investigation, I discovered that the issue was due to the Jenkins job not being created or configured beforehand. The curl command was trying to trigger a build for a job that didn’t exist, and as a result, the build couldn’t be triggered.
To resolve this, I created a new job in Jenkins with the same name, subbu_project. After doing this, I triggered the GitHub Actions workflow again. This time, the workflow successfully connected to Jenkins using the provided credentials and triggered the new build, completing the process.
Here is the GitHub Action output log after creating  201 Created the job in Jenkins:
Output for the quick reference:
Executing curl command:
< HTTP/1.1 201 Created
< Date: Sat, 31 Aug 2024 10:46:33 GMT
< X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff
< Location: ***/queue/item/6/
< Content-Length: 0
< Server: Jetty(10.0.20)

